# Overflow in Chrome 41

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

[image: Screenshot of the site]

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36

[Bug report on Meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253550/256282)

Comment: Same issue in FF/37.0.1 on OSX 10.10.3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4lVQx.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A fix for this is rolling out now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253555/130213)

Comment: Thanks k-Dawg (that's your name now btw), and quick turn-around too!